# Python - Extract information from plist/xml

Tags: python

This is my plist/xml (I've shortened it a bit, but it's still huge, so I put it as a link: https://ghostbin.com/paste/rbu9t

What I want to do is extract the fields like:

appIdentifier
className
*function* <--- Function = The line after "displayname".

What I've got right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LFxH.gif

But if I continue the pattern, it will extract wrong stuff.

I want to be able to extarct all functions and classnames for each app before I go to the next one.

And if that isnt possible, then I want to be able to extract all classes and functions, but with a plist/xml that only has the information of one app.

> **OLD QUESTION:** I'm coding a program, but as you can see, I'm doing +6 then +1, then +6, then +1. Is there a way to automate this (some program or site) or some code to help me? Cheers!

My code: (*note: the number pattern won't really help as much as I thought, since each app can have different amounts of classes and functions.

```
import xml.dom.minidom

xml = xml.dom.minidom.parse('my.plist')

Document = xml.getElementsByTagName('plist')



for key in Document:
    desc = key.getElementsByTagName('string')[5].firstChild.data
    desc1 = key.getElementsByTagName('string')[6].firstChild.data

print('Class: ', desc, 'Function: ', desc1)


desc = key.getElementsByTagName('string')[11].firstChild.data
desc1 = key.getElementsByTagName('string')[12].firstChild.data

print('Class: ', desc, 'Function: ', desc1)


desc = key.getElementsByTagName('string')[17].firstChild.data
desc1 = key.getElementsByTagName('string')[18].firstChild.data

print('Class: ', desc, 'Function: ', desc1)

desc = key.getElementsByTagName('string')[23].firstChild.data
desc1 = key.getElementsByTagName('string')[24].firstChild.data

print('Class: ', desc, 'Function: ', desc1)


desc = key.getElementsByTagName('string')[29].firstChild.data
desc1 = key.getElementsByTagName('string')[30].firstChild.data

print('Class: ', desc, 'Function: ', desc1)
```

Sorry if the post isn't very detailed or explained, if you have any questions I'll answer them as good as I can!

Comment: your indentation makes little sense. Please fix it.

Comment: BTW, I'd be very surprised if you actually had a reason to do numerical indexing here -- if we were given the actual format of your input XML, I'll bet we could provide an answer that didn't involve knowing the relative offset at all, and would still work if that changed in the future.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I hope so! Updating post now! :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Updated!

Comment: Is it important that this be implemented in Python? Looking at the problem, my first temptation is to write something in shell using XMLStarlet.

Comment: Hmm. Oddly, that pastebin seems to be one line off from being syntactically valid XML -- I had to delete an extra `</dict>` near the end.

Comment: See an XQuery implementation and its output at https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/c0b2c44ced389e52ba74bdd0b601980a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier with a modern XML library supporting XPath; thus, I'm using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) below.

```
import lxml.etree as etree
import sys

doc = etree.parse(open(sys.argv[1]))
for app_dict in doc.xpath('/plist/dict/array/dict'):
    appId = app_dict.xpath('./key[.="appIdentifier"]/following-sibling::string[1]/text()')[0]
    for method_dict in app_dict.xpath('.//dict[key="methodObjc"]/dict'):
        classId = method_dict.xpath('./key[.="className"]/following-sibling::string[1]/text()')[0]
        methodId = method_dict.xpath('./key[.="displayName"]/following-sibling::string[1]/text()')[0] 
        print 'App: %s; Class: %s; Method: %s' % (appId, classId, methodId)
```

Full output is:

```
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBInAppPurchasesManager; Method: -(bool) isPremium
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBRedeemCodeView; Method: -(unsigned long long) reward
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBGetFollowersGoldenFollowersCell; Method: -(void) setFreeFollowers:(long long)
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBGetFollowersGoldenFollowersCell; Method: -(long long) freeFollowers
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBSettings; Method: -(double) extraRewardForPro
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBSettings; Method: -(void) setReferralMinReward:(long long)
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBSettings; Method: -(long long) referralMinReward
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBSettings; Method: -(void) setRewardForSecondaryAccount:(long long)
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBSettings; Method: -(long long) rewardForSecondaryAccount
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBSettings; Method: -(void) setExtraRewardForPro:(double)
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBMe; Method: -(unsigned long long) availableSpins
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBMe; Method: -(bool) canRedeemCode
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBMe; Method: -(void) setCanRedeemCode:(bool)
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBSettings; Method: -(bool) wofFreeSpinsEnabled
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBSettings; Method: -(void) setWofFreeSpinsEnabled:(bool)
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBWheelOfFortuneView; Method: -(long long) numberOfFreeSpins
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBWheelOfFortuneView; Method: -(void) setNumberOfFreeSpins:(long long)
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBWheelOfFortunePrizeView; Method: -(bool) freeSpinAvailable
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBWheelOfFortunePrizeView; Method: -(void) setFreeSpinAvailable:(bool)
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBWheelOfFortuneManager; Method: -(bool) freeSpinAvailable
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBMiniGame; Method: -(void) setPrize:(id)
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBMiniGame; Method: -(id) prize
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBSettings; Method: -(unsigned long long) maxEnergyDefault
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBSettings; Method: -(void) setMaxEnergyDefault:(unsigned long long)
App: com.betternet; Class: BetternetUser; Method: -(bool) isPremium
App: com.betternet; Class: BetternetUser; Method: -(void) setIsPremium:(bool)
App: com.betternet; Class: BetternetUser; Method: -(bool) allowedPremium
App: com.betternet; Class: GADDevice; Method: -(bool) jailbroken
App: com.betternet; Class: FlurryUtil; Method: +(BOOL) deviceIsJailbroken
App: co.allconnected.vpnmaster; Class: FlurryUtil; Method: +(BOOL) deviceIsJailbroken
App: com.anchorfree.hss; Class: ZDKUser; Method: -(bool) isAgent
App: com.anchorfree.hss; Class: AFUserAccount; Method: -(void) setAuto_renew:(bool)
App: com.anchorfree.hss; Class: AFUserAccount; Method: -(bool) auto_renew
App: com.anchorfree.hss; Class: AFUserAccount; Method: -(void) setIsValid:(bool)
App: com.apprizon.follow4followapp; Class: IBInAppPurchasesManager; Method: -(bool) isPremium
App: com.alphaweb.fairyfail; Class: IBBearGood; Method: -(float) speed
App: com.alphaweb.fairyfail; Class: GameScene; Method: -(int) totalNumberOfStars
App: com.alphaweb.fairyfail; Class: BalloonSprite; Method: -(float) speed
App: com.alphaweb.fairyfail; Class: GameScene; Method: -(BOOL) rateMenuShouldBeDisplayed
App: com.alphaweb.fairyfail; Class: GameScene; Method: -(BOOL) isSpiderExist
App: com.alphaweb.fairyfail; Class: IBBearBomb; Method: -(BOOL) isBomb
App: com.intsig.CamScannerHDPro; Class: CSDataCenter; Method: +(bool) isPremiumAccount
App: com.intsig.CamScannerHDPro; Class: CSLoggedinViewController; Method: -(bool) isPremiumAccount
App: com.intsig.CamScannerHDPro; Class: ENSession; Method: -(bool) isPremiumUser
App: com.intsig.CamScannerHDPro; Class: CSSettings; Method: +(bool) isPremiumFeatureAvailable
App: com.intsig.CamScannerHDPro; Class: CSStoreManager; Method: -(int) faxBalance
App: com.intsig.CamScannerHDPro; Class: CSStoreManager; Method: -(void) setFaxBalance:(int)
App: com.intsig.CamScannerHDPro; Class: CSStoreManager; Method: -(bool) canSendFax
App: com.intsig.CamScannerHDPro; Class: CSStoreManager; Method: -(void) setCanSendFax:(bool)
App: com.intsig.CamScannerHDPro; Class: CSHDAppDelegate; Method: -(void) collectInfos
```

Comment: I get this error: 
    doc = lxml.etree.parse(open(sys.argv[1]))
NameError: name 'lxml' is not defined'

Comment: Oops -- sorry, just `etree.parse`, since the import has `as etree`.

Comment: That fixed it :)
Now I got 

 `doc = etree.parse(open(sys.argv[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range'`


Also, where do I enter my file name?

Comment: Pass the filename on the command line to your program. That'll put it in `sys.argv[1]`. Or just substitute it into that position some other way, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I really appreciate your work :D It works perfectly, now I'm just trying to understand the code to see what you did, I'm pretty new to python :)

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 5
for key in Document:
    desc = key.getElementsByTagName('string')[x].firstChild.data
    desc1 = key.getElementsByTagName('string')[x+1].firstChild.data
    print('Class: ', desc, 'Function: ', desc1)
    x += 5
```

can you try above code snippet, hope this helps

Comment: if found helpful, please do accept it as the correct answer